# how to access rows and columns of a select query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

```
var r=db.execute("query")
```

Hi! I wanna access the columns (and rows) obtained from this query (like q[0].column1). But when I store it in a var it is not possible.

What kind of datatype or technique can I use?

Is there a difference between single row output and multiple row output when doing this?

I am working with sql server CE db (sdf file) in webmatrix.

Comment: What type does `execute` return? What type is `db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that db is an object of [Database type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) from the WebMatrix.Data namespace, opened with a command like

```
var db = Database.Open("yourDb");
```

If this is right, the Execute method (with the capital E) doesn't return a query, but an integer that is the count of records affected by the SQL statement executed (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE).

The methods that return the result of a query are three: Query, QuerySingle and QueryValue.

Query returns a list of rows as IEnumerable of Objects. The following example queries a Northwind table and displays the result:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE SupplierID = 1");
    foreach (var row in data){
        <p>@row.ProductID - @row.ProductName</p>
    }
}
```

QuerySingle returns a single row as Object, e.g.:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var data = db.QuerySingle("SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = 10");
    <p>@data.ProductID - @data.ProductName</p>
}
```

QueryValue returns a single value as Object:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var data = db.QueryValue("SELECT UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductID = 14");
    <p>The price of product n. 14 is: @data</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DB is going to return a table or a dataset. In order, to access the data in each cell you need to loop through the DataTable or DataSet rows and specify each column index or name.